# Round Edges on solidified mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode

I am trying to create a piece of clothing.

As you can see I created a simple shirt which has nice smooth round edges. Around neckline, arms opening and the bottom piece.[image]

However the mesh topology in edit mode is bad. Many verts are not connected and the sheer amount of verts which create the round edges is too high. Total vert count is 8776. There are simply too many verts and edges and no way for me to connect and merge all of the verts.

[image]

Any way to create these round edges? I have tried using bevel modifier but that doesnt create anything but highlist the quads.

I would like to create a similar look from mesh on the last picture. The edges and faces on it are flat. The vert count is 886. I dont even mind 8000 verts as long as I dont have to go through 5000 merging them.

Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [proportional editing mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html)? If not, that might be worth a shot. Rough outline of how I would go about it:

- Bridge the edge loops (works best if both loops have the same number of verts)
- Do several loop cuts on the face loop added to create the bridge
- Turn on proportional editing mode and set it to "Sphere" or "Smooth"
- Select the inner most ring of the loop cuts
- Grab and move or scale the selected loop

[image: proportional editing example]

Comment: Thank you! That worked! 

Is it possible to UV unwrap only the new loops/vertices while keeping the old UV map? Sort of add the new ones to the already existing UV map?

Comment: In theory what you describe should be possible with Blender (or maybe with an add-on like [TexTools](http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/)), but I am not very familiar with this area of Blender. As this is a different topic, I would recommend posting this as a new question if you want to get more input on this.